# Xamarin forms two way binding date property time reset

Tags: c#, xamarin, model-view-controller, xamarin.forms, two-way-binding

I am assigning a date value to a two-way binding property in my view model. The time portion of the date gets reset to 12:00 am after the assignment. The SelectedAvailableSlot.EndDate time is 3 am but it beccomes 12 am. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private DateTime selectedEndDate;
        public DateTime SelectedEndDate
        {
            get => selectedEndDate;
            set
            {
                if (selectedEndDate == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                SetProperty(ref selectedEndDate, value);
            }
        }
```

// =========== Assignment =============//

```
 SelectedEndDate = SelectedAvailableSlot.EndDate;
```

Comment: there must be something else going on in your code to cause this.  Are you sure the control the property is bound to is not the culprit?  Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the setter?

Comment: Perhaps the control is set to display "Date Only". Please show the XAML for the control you have bound to. Also, put `Debug.WriteLine($"{value}")` before and `Debug.WriteLine($"{selectedEndDate}")` after `SetProperty`,  I am certain that you will discover that SetProperty simply copies value to selectedEndDate. Proving that it isn't the problem. Perhaps you will first see an incoming value with 3 AM. THEN you'll see an incoming value that has 12 AM - from the control.

Comment: Also, show the actual assignment statement that does something like `...SelectedEndDate = myOriginalValue;`  With breakpoint on that line, and another breakpoint in SelectedEndDate setter, you should see, when you execute that assignment, that it does send in 3 AM. (And then I hypothesize that the control strips that off, calling setter a second time.)